# Terms of a series equal to zero

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers.
If $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$: $\sum_{k=0}^{+ \infty} a_k k^n = 0$.
Is it true that $a_k=0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

It looks like a problem of orthogonality in an Hilbert space, but I am not sure here because the sequence $k^n$ is not convergent.

Comment: What about  $a_1=4$, $a_2=-1$ and $a_n=0$ for all $n\geq 2$?

Comment: For $n=0$ in my statement $a_1 + a_2$ is not equal to $0$ in your example.

Comment: I misread the quantifiers on your statement, sorry for that.

Comment: I don't have the time to investigate further right now, but the coefficients of the taylor series for $e^{1/(x-1)}$ about $x=0$ might give a counter-example.